# L-hospital Rule in the Partial Derivative By Definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm having an exam of multivariate calculus . I'm not able to solve a question.

The Question is:

$$f(x,y) = e^x (\cos y +x \sin y)$$ Show that $F_{xy} = F_{yx}$ at Origin by Definition

Hint : use L-hospital use to solve the question.

Here is the link of the snap of my register copy that explains what I've done. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjZYc.jpg

As in the snap, I'm stuck as if I apply the limit, that makes the denominator zero and infinity should not be a correct ans I believe.

I'm stuck as if I apply the limit, that makes the denominator zero and infinity should not be a correct ans I believe.

I would really appreciate if someone would help me understand how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Hi Jose, Thanks alot for the quick response. Sure. Here is the link of the snap of my register copy. 
http://i.imgur.com/XMAX4ny.jpg

I'm stuck as if I apply the limit, that makes the denominator zero and infinity should not be a correct ans I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding first:
$$f(x,y) = e^x \cos y + x e^x \sin y$$
$$f_{xy} = (f_x)_y= \frac {{\partial }^2f}{{\partial x}{\partial y}}$$ $$f_{yx} = (f_y)_x= \frac {{\partial }^2f}{{\partial y}{\partial x}}$$
$$f_{x} = e^x \cos y + e^x \sin y  +x e^x \sin y$$
$$f_{xy} = -e^x \sin y + e^x\cos y + x e^x \cos y$$
Evaluating this at $(0,0)$ gives: $f_{xy}= 1$
Now :
$$f_{y} = -e^x \sin y +xe^x \cos y$$
$$f_{yx}= - e^x \sin y + e^x \cos y + xe^x \cos y$$
Evaluating this at $(0,0)$ gives: $f_{yx} =1$.
Hence: $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ at the origin.